# error attempting to bind openlayers map on click event

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

I want to get the lat/long from the openlayers map object when click the map.  I've tried to do it with Map.on('click',function(e){})

but an error occurs.  From the console I've capture the following:

> "Uncaught TypeError: map.on is not a function"

---

**code:**

```
  <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script>

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 114.5931866, -3.3171685 )
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
            map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
          );

    var zoom=16;

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);

    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));
    map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);


    map.on('click',function(evt){
      var coords = ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate);
      var lat = coords[1];
      var lon = coords[0];
      var loctxt = "latitude : " + lat + " Longitude: "+ lon;
      alert(loctxt);
    });


  </script>

</body></html>
```

I expected it will show alert of the latlong on click map

Comment: Here's an example of handling click events in OpenLayers 2 http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/click.html

Comment: the map.on used to work btw with 5.3.0 (had a project using it on July 2019) and seems to not be working now (September 2020), even though I still reference the same library (https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js)

Comment: the app that was using OpenLayers 5.3.0 fine and now is broken (tried on both Edge-Chromium and Firefox on Windows) is at http://photodentro.edu.gr/photodentro/MultiHeightMeterEU_v2.0_pidx0015986/

Comment: Eureka: found a fix for the same issue I was having. To avoid imports (and work in older browsers) I was doing var Map = ol.Map; and later on doing a new Map(...), but it was using Map javascript object ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead. So now I just use new ol.Map(...) in the code and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error you've shared is a typical js error that occurs when accessing a property like a function.  Two things:

1. Pull the version of openlayers corresponding with the map.on approach from which you've copied code.  Otherwise, and unless intentionally using an old version, try referencing the latest [OpenLayers library](https://openlayers.org/download/). it appears that the asset loaded by  `<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>` is OpenLayers 2.13.1 which is from 2013.
2. in 5.3.0, using the MousePosition control will provide the corresponding lat/long per the [mouse-position demo](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mouse-position.html) provided in the OpenLayers documentation site.  Their example provides how to target elements on mouse position change, you can use that information during a click event.  Below is an example I've provided which when added to the mouse-position demo clicks log lat/long to the console:

   `document.getElementById("map").addEventListener('click', 
     function(e) { 
      console.log(document.getElementById("mouse-position").childNodes[0].innerHTML)
     });`